# Can we find a proper $\phi$ so that maps each interval to its center?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algorithms, combinations, recursive-algorithms

For a compact interval $[0,1]$, we divide it into $N^{1/3}$ subintervals with length $N^{-1/3}$. Define a map $\phi: [0,1]\mapsto [0,1]$ maps each subintervals to its center.

For example, let $X\sim Uniform[0,1]$ and $N=1$. Then there is only interval $[0,1]$ and we maps each point to $1/2$. If $X=0.1$, then $\phi(X)=0.5$.

For general $N=1000$, each subinterval with length $1000^{-1/3}=0.1$. How to find a map such that
$
\phi(X)
$ is equal to the center of that subinterval?

Like if $X=0.34$, we need $\phi(0.34)=0.35$ which is the center of $[0.3, 0.4]$.

I found an approximate way that takes $\phi(X)=N^{1/3}\times [N^{1/3}X]$. But this is not very properly, especially for $N=1,2,3,4,...,10$. For example, if $N=1000$, $X=0.57$, then
$$
\phi(0.57)=1000^{1/3}\times [1000^{1/3}0.57]=0.6
$$
but not the median of $[0.5,0.6]$ which should be $0.55$.

***Question***: Can we find a proper $\phi$?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? For instance, if we write $[x \in P]$ for the function which is $1$ if $x \in P$ and $0$ if $x \not \in P$, then (assuming $N^{1/3}$ is an integer)
$$\sum_{i=0}^{N^{1/3} - 1} \frac{i + (i+1)}{2 N^{1/3}} \left [ x \in \left ( i N^{-1/3}, (i+1) N^{-1/3} \right ) \right ]$$
works, and can be adjusted to have whatever behavior you like on the region boundaries.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Can you explain more details? I try to construct such a function $\phi$ and write it code in Python. So you $\phi(x)=\sum \frac{i+(i+1)}{2N^{1/3}}1[(iN^{-1/3}, (i+1_N^{-1/3})$ where $1$ is the indicator function.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Yes, your formula works. How to get this expression?